# IDependencyResolver in MVC Project with Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm going through the book, "Pro ASP.NET MVC 5, 5th ed" by Freeman and something is not making sense. In case anyone's following along, this is chapter 6. The author uses Ninject for DI.

The *NinjectWebWebCommons.cs* file has a method, `RegisterServices()` where we specify our `IDependencyResolver` implementation:

```cs
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel) {
    // This is where we tell MVC to use our custom DependencyResolver.
    System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new
        EssentialTools.Infrastructure.NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
}
```

I put a breakpoint on the above code and it's hit, as expected.

Now I go into the `EssentialTools.Infrastructure.NinjectDependencyResolver` class. This is the class that implements `IDependencyResolver`. The class' c'tor looks like this:

```cs
public NinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernelParam) {
    kernel = kernelParam;

    kernel.Bind<IValueCalculator>().To<LinqValueCalculator>().InRequestScope();
    kernel.Bind<IDiscountHelper>().To<DefaultDiscountHelper>().WithPropertyValue("DiscountSize", 2.5M);
    kernel.Bind<IDiscountHelper>().To<FlexibleDiscountHelper>().WhenInjectedInto<LinqValueCalculator>();
}
```

Putting a breakpoint in the c'tor also works. The breakpoint is hit.

Since the `NinjectDependencyResolver` class implements `IDependencyResolver`, it has these two interface implementation methods:

```cs
public object GetService(Type serviceType) {
    return kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
}
```

and

```cs
public object GetServices(Type serviceType) {
    return kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
}
```

Here's what I'm not understanding – neither of these two methods is getting called! I even replaced the two methods' contents with:

```cs
throw null;
```

and everything still worked fine. No exception was thrown.

Can someone explain why neither of these methods is being called? My (probably incorrect) understanding is that the MVC framework will call these methods to retrieve implementations of a particular `Type`, yet these methods are never being called.

Comment: Is it because the services are lazy loaded? Have you tried to call a method in the service in your controller?

Comment: @Shawn Song - Yes, methods in the service are called, so I don't think it's an issue of lazy loading.

Comment: @Tom Baxter did you ever understand what is going on here?

Comment: @Ian - No, I never did.